# Delete specific columns

Tags: r, if-statement, break, col

I have

```
F <- structure(c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), .Dim = c(3L, 
5L))
```

How can I remove from F the columns that have less than 2 consecutive zero?
Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `rle` to determine the consecutive values i.e. 0 and create a logical condition with `lengths` by looping over the column (`apply`, `MARGIN = 2`)

```
F[,!apply(F, 2, function(x) with(rle(!x), 
      any(lengths >= 2 & values))), drop = FALSE]
```

-output

```
      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    1    1
[3,]    1    1
```

If it is the opposite, just remove the `!`

```
F[,apply(F, 2, function(x) with(rle(!x), 
      any(lengths >= 2 & values))), drop = FALSE]
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
```

Comment: This way I don't delete the columns from F, it only highlights the ones that should be deleted

Comment: @ros_ber sorry, I thought it was the opposite you needed.  Updated

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach with `rle` applied over the columns:

```r
F[, apply(F, 2, \(x) with(rle(x), any(lengths[values == 0] >= 2)))]

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pure `base`, no extra functions, as one-liner:

```
U = F[, apply((F[-1,]==0) & (F[-nrow(F),]==0), 2, any)]
```

Breakdown:

```
U = F[                                   # Select...
   ,                                     # ...all the rows in the matrix...
   apply(                                # ...that have...
      (F[-nrow(F),]==0) & (F[-1,]==0),   # ...one value = 0 and the next value = 0
      2,                                 # ...in columns (i.e. 2nd dimension)....
      any                                # ...anywhere in the column.
    )
]
```